# Strange char with readline on terminal app

Tags: php, terminal, console, char, readline

I am writing php-console app with readline use for user input commands.

This is how I am using it:

```
$input = readline("\033$label\033\n");
```

And it looks like this in cmd terminal:

[image]

But with this same terminal in vscode this questions marks are not visible. When I remove color codes ("\033", "\033") they dissapears.

I tested this app in cygwin terminal too and questions marks are not visible, but in this places are two space symbols.

Please for help.

Comment: Different terminal emulators use different control codes, and Windows' various terminals are guaranteed not compatible with linux terminals.

Comment: In windows terminal (cmd) there are two chars and in linux terminal (cygwin) there are two symbols. Difference is that in windows they are visible, in cygwin they are invisible but instead of symbol I see two spaces

Comment: Then those are two different methods of dealing with unintelligible input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output correct control codes in accordance with the terminal emulator being used. What works in an xterm emulator may not in vt100 or whatever Windows uses.

1. You can use the function [`stream_isatty(STDOUT)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-isatty.php) to detect if the output is a terminal.
2. You can refer to the constants [`PHP_OS_FAMILY` or `PHP_OS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to detect the OS you're currently running on.
3. On linux [or emulated equivalent, like cygwin] you can refer to the environment variable `$_ENV['TERM']` to determine which terminal emulator is in use.

Based on these three pieces of information you can determine whether or not to use "fancy" output formatting, and output the control codes appropriate to a given terminal emulator.

Comment: So in windows I can't use colored output or I should use another once which is accordance with windows (if this exists)? Can you give informations source about colors?

Comment: I know virtually nothing about formatting for Windows terminal other than I don't think I've ever seen colored output in a cmd terminal. The "new" terminal that PowerShell uses does seem to have color support, though.